# Why does '0.2 + 0.1' show as '0.30000000000000004'?

Tags: python, floating-point, append, decimal

I have written the following code for generating a range with floats:

```
def drange(start, stop, step):
    result = []
    value = start
    while value <= stop:
        result.append(value)
        value += step
    return result
```

When calling this function with this statement:

```
print drange(0.1,1.0,0.1)
```

I expected to obtain this:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]
```

But I obtain the following, instead:

```
[0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999]
```

Why is this?, and how can I fix it?

Comment: floats are not precise. please read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Here is a nice explanation on how floating point arithmetic works in Python https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @timgeb No, that's an atrocious resource for most people's needs. There are [better options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260130/canonical-duplicate-for-floating-point-is-inaccurate#comment40519_260130).

Comment: I don't mind that most people, on encountering issues like this, don't know enough to search for topics like floating point representation. However *this exact sum, in Python*, already has an answered question. In future, *search* before asking.

Answer (score 9):

That's how floating-point numbers work. You can't represent an infinite number of real numbers in a finite number of bits, so there is some truncation. You should take a look at **[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**:

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Use `round(number, k)` to round a given floating-point value to `k` digits after the decimal (so in your case, use `round(number, 1)` for one digit).